# Float with either comma ',' or '.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am experiencing a problem in Asp.net using C# when converting a string to float. At a local database, it works fine with '.' notation for float values but it does not work after uploading the website to the server. I think the server only understands ',' instead of '.'

I remember I read this somewhere that I can add some culture Info into the web.config in order to get float understand either '.' or ','

And how can I change it globally for a WinForm application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please eliminate confusion by correcting the question tags `asp.net` or your question `WinForm application`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can but you shouldn't. If it's implicit to your code's purpose that it should use `.` as the decimal separator then you should explicitly use the appropriate CultureInfo:

```
double d = double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // uses format with . as decimal separator, no matter what the current culture is.
```

It's only if you want to parse according to a given culture that you should use a CultureInfo, as set in the web.config `<globalization>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

For WinForms, you can't do it globally (assuming by 'globaly' you don't mean setting locale on windows), because the culture is specific to Thread. But you can do it programatically with `Thread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentUICulture`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globalization section for Web.Config.

```
e.g:  <globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

Link : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

For windows forms, you can assign the CulturInfo to the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.